# How can I properly display an image that is in my database?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm actually trying to display an image that someone submit via a form, to use it as a profile picture.
When I try to display it, it just show a white square so that's the problem.
I have a column "image" in my database and I'm using the "blob" type.

This is were I try to display the image :

```
  <div class="menu_connect_big_screen">
                <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, {{ Auth::user()->image }}" />
                <p>{{Auth::user()->firstName}} {{Auth::user()->lastName}}</p>
                <a href="{{ url('/my_account') }}">Mon compte</a> | <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Se déconnecter</a>
            </div>
```

This is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;


class ProfilePictureController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request)
    {

        $request = $request->All();
            User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->update(
                    [
                        'image' => base64_encode($request['image'])
                    ]
                );
            return redirect()->to('/')->with(['image-changed' => 'Photo de profil modifiée !']);
        }

}
```

And that's the form were you can submit the image :

```
 <form action="{{ route('profilePicture') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            <div id="profile-container">
                            <image id="profileImage" src="{{url('images/user.jpg')}}" />
                        </div>
                        <input id="imageUpload" type="file"
                               name="image" placeholder="Photo" accept="image/*"  capture>
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0" >
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4" >
                                <button type="submit"   class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Enregistrer') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Without recreating the project, it's a tricky one to debug. However I have noticed that you are allowing any image type in your form but when rendering the image your are only allowing `image/jpg` to be rendered. Also as a starting point. I would dump out the value of `Auth::user()->image` and decrypting this using an online tool. This will tell you if it's an issue saving the image or rendering it.

Comment: I think the problem is how I'm saving the image